# How to do one hot encoded and get the number of classes programatically in Python? For artificial neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a list called `y_train` that looks like this

```
[   307    307    307 ... 257947 257947 257947]
```

The `307, 257947` are all distinct IDs that I want to do one hot encoding on. It has a total of 480 classes. The list `y_train` has a length of 10799 also as the number of rows. How can I do one hot encoding on this so that it shows that it has 480 class and 10799 rows? I'm trying to fit this in a tensorflow model.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. One of the methods is to use [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to convert categorical variables into dummy/indicator variables.

Example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                   'C': [1, 2, 3]})

pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=['col1', 'col2'])
   C  col1_a  col1_b  col2_a  col2_b  col2_c
0  1       1       0       0       1       0
1  2       0       1       1       0       0
2  3       1       0       0       0       1
```

Another method is to use Scikit-learn's [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)